# How to temporarily stop clicking effect before changing adapter data?

Tags: android, android-listview

### background

When choosing an item from a listView, I change its data and call notifyDataSetChanged.

### The problem

Since it's the same listView, when I click the item, the effect stays for the view that will be used after the notifyDataSetChanged.

This is especially noticeable on Android Lollipop, where the ripple can continue after the listView gets refreshed with new data.

### The code

Here's a sample code showing the problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
  {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter()
    {
    int pressCount=0;

    @Override
    public int getCount()
      {
      return 100;
      }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
      {
      return null;
      }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
      {
      return 0;
      }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
      {
      View rootView=convertView;
      if(rootView==null)
        {
        rootView=LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parent,false);
        rootView.setBackgroundResource(getResIdFromAttribute(MainActivity.this,android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground));
        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
          {
          pressCount++;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
        });
        }
      TextView tv=(TextView)rootView;
      tv.setText("text:"+(pressCount+position));
      return rootView;
      }
    });
    }

  public static int getResIdFromAttribute(final Activity activity,final int attr)
    {
    if(attr==0)
      return 0;
    final TypedValue typedvalueattr=new TypedValue();
    activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr,typedvalueattr,true);
    return typedvalueattr.resourceId;
    }

  }
```

### The question

How can I temporarily stop the selection effect till the next time anything is clicked on the listView (but also resume allowing it for the next time the user clicks an item) ?

Comment: temporarily make your view.setClickable(false) / isFocusable as false..

Comment: Where exactly should I put it ? in the listener? Also, where should I restore it? on getView() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer. It seems it's a known issue, and the solution is quite simple (shown [**here**](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/12/15/animated-drawables-lollipop/)) :

```
ViewCompat.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(view);
```

Weird thing is, it works for me only when I call it via Handler.post(...) .

Wonder why (as the view is already during animation), and if there's a better solution.

Comment: For me it works when I call it on list view itself, not the item's view. No Handler.post(...) required in my case.